# VBA Trapezoidal integration method

Tags: vba

I have a function of `1500/(1+x*.0042)` that is integrated from 0 to 950, and I am to do so with trapezoidal method. `n` refers to the number of trapezoids. I am not getting any output for my function. please help if you can.

```
Function TotalArea(n As Double) As Double
    Dim a As Double
    Dim b As Double
    Dim dx As Double
    Dim i As Double
    a = 0
    b = 950
    dx = (b - a) / n
    TotalArea = 0
    For i = 0 To 950 Step dx
     TotalArea = TotalArea + (((1500 / (1 + i * 0.0042) + 1500 / (1 + (i + dx) * 0.0042))))
    Next i
    TotalArea = TotalArea / 2
End Function
```

Comment: Please fix the layout of your code. Indent each line of code with 4 spaces so it gets displayed as code instead of regular text.

Comment: It seems to return values fine here.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to use the function name as a variable within the function, but your code does return values.

You might want to consider below (mathematically simplified):

```
Option Explicit

Function TotalArea(n As Double) As Double
    Const k As Double = 1500
    Const r As Double = 0.0042

    Dim a As Double
    Dim b As Double
    Dim dx As Double
    Dim i As Double
    Dim Area As Double

    a = 0
    b = 950
    dx = (b - a) / n
    Area = 0
    For i = a To b Step dx
        Debug.Print "i: " & i & " (dx: " & dx & ", Area: " & Area & ")"
        Area = Area + ((1 / (1 + i * r) + 1 / (1 + (i + dx) * r)))
    Next i
    TotalArea = k * Area / 2
End Function
```